# property is used class linq

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to put data into class using LINQ.

class Person

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Surname { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to add 2 person and next find person with id 1 and later edit name. Do you know how to do it?

```
 public List<Person> persons { get; set; }
 public void example()
 {
 persons = new List<Person>();
 }
```

something like that?

```
new List<Person>{
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "sadsad",
                    Surname = new string Suname {Surname="Examle"}

                };


                persons = (from a in Person
                                     where a.Id = 1
                                   select a).FirstOrDefault<Ankieta>();

                string s = persons.Name; // Update?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding 2 persons

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>{
        new Person(){
        Id = 1,
        Name = "sadsad",
        Surname = new List<string>(){"Examle"}
        },

        new Person(){
        Id = 2,
        Name = "fbs",
        Surname = new List<string>(){"ggg"}
        }};

// adding another person
persons.Add(new Person() { Id = 3, Name = "cc", Surname = new List<string>() { "ggg" } });
```

find person with id 1 and later edit name using `ForEach`

```
persons.ForEach(p => p.Name = (p.Id == 1) ? "NewName" : p.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I'd type Surname as a`string`:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
persons.Add(new Person(){ Id = 1, Name = "Name", Surname = "Surname" });
//...
var result = (from a in persons where a.Id == 1 select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for help I gave you point for support.